# How much safe is socket.io?

Tags: security, socket.io

i'm studying socket.io for exchange of sensitive data between clients. I don't understand exactly how socket.io works, and so  how much safe is data send using .emit() method.
Should i care about using some cryptographic method on data before sending or can i trust it is secure?

I'm worry about man-in-the-middle attack.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to worry about doing the crypto yourself.  Just run session over TLS and make sure that the server's certificate gets validated.